# How do I use a conditional to exclude an element from an include on only one page?

Tags: php

I have a generic include that contains secondary navigation, etc. that is included on every page of a site. It also contains a graphic that I want to appear on every page but the home page. I realize that it would be trivial to do this client side and just remove the node from the DOM on load on that one page, but for various reasons I want to do this server side.

I have this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') {
    echo "";
}
else {
    echo "<img src=\"img/foobar.gif\" width=\"60\" height=\"96\" alt=\"description\" />";
}
?>
```

This works for `domain.com/index.php`, but I can't figure out how to get it to work for both `domain.com/index.php` and `domain.com/`. My experiments with the OR operator caused the graphic to disappear from all pages (because every page includes the root domain in the path). Help me out PHP gurus!

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' )
```